# SQL showing summary after each column value changes

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have sales data for branches. I want a SQL which will give me summary of sales data for each branchId as below, of course BranchId(s) are huge so I have to make it dynamic (I can't use Union). I am stuck how to add a summary row after every branch change dynamically.

```
+ ---------+--------+---------+-----------+
| BranchId | CashIn | CashOut | CardSales |
+ ---------+--------+---------+-----------+
| 1        |   1000 |     500 |        50 |
| 1        |    500 |    2500 |       100 |
| 1        |   1000 |     200 |       200 |
| Totals   |   2500 |    3200 |       350 |
| 5        |    100 |     500 |       500 |
| Totals   |    100 |     500 |       500 |
| 7        |    100 |     100 |       100 |
| 7        |    200 |     300 |       400 |
| Totals   |    300 |     400 |       500 |
+ ---------+--------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Oracle query to calculate subtotal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43979507/sql-oracle-query-to-calculate-subtotal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brute force method is to do the aggregation and then interleave the results:

```
select (case when is_base = 1 then to_char(BranchId)
             else replace('Total ([BranchId])', '[BranchId]', BranchId)
        end) as BranchId, CashIn, CashOut, CardSales
from ((select BranchId, CashIn, CashOut, CardSales, 1 as is_base
       from t
      ) union all
      (select BranchId, sum(CashIn), sum(CashOut), sum(CardSales), 0 as is_base
       from t
       group by BranchId
      )
     ) t
order by t.BranchId, is_base desc;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c5807fccf58021023f2fc91557904429) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @AnkurBhutani . . . I added a db<>fiddle and fixed a couple of typos.